# How to find the confidence score of svm model?

Tags: function, model, svm, probability, prediction

While going through the different evaluation methods for model, I had tried some text classification using svm model which has lots of features,and after training the model, it is able to classify the text.

But my question is, if I want to calculate the confidence score of svm model? I have checked lots of examples using predict_proba and decision function.

Many of times, predict_proba doesn't align with the model prediction and gives wrong probabilities and if I use decision function then how would i interpret the distance as confidence score? How we should define the threshold?

Comment: SVM in its usual formulation can't output a confidence or probability value. There are various hacks to get one, but my advice is to use a different kind of model if you want a confidence or probability. Also you'll probably get more interest in such questions at stat.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I used SVM model because I have a large feature sets and lots of target values which needs to classify, and I think in this case,SVM should prefer.
If not SVM, then which model?
Thoughts?